# Taylor series expansion of quantile function

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, approximation-theory, taylor-series

Suppose $Y$ and $Z$ two random variables, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R} $.

We note $F^{-1}_{Y}(\alpha)$ the quantile function of the variable $Y$ at the quantile level $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

Do you have any idea how to obtain this Taylor series expansion formula ?
$$F^{-1}_{Y+\lambda Z}(\alpha)=F^{-1}_{Y}(\alpha)+\lambda[\frac{dF^{-1}_{Y+\lambda Z}}{d\lambda}(\alpha)]_{\lambda = 0} + \frac{\lambda^2}{2!}[\frac{d^2 F^{-1}_{Y+\lambda Z}}{d\lambda^2}(\alpha)]_{\lambda = 0}+...+\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}[\frac{d^n F^{-1}_{Y+\lambda Z}}{d\lambda^n}(\alpha)]_{\lambda = 0}+...$$

Comment: This is just the usual formula for a Taylor series.  Or do you mean you want to find the coefficients?

Comment: To have any hope of analyticity, I think you'll want to assume $Y$ and $Z$ have a joint distribution with a density.

Comment: The approximation of a usual Taylor formula is usually at the value of $\alpha$ and not at the functions. So, this formula is not evident for me and I don't know how to prove it (or find the coefficients).

Yes, we can suppose that $Y$ and $Z$ have a joint distribution with a density.

Comment: An example may help:  Suppose X and Y are both lognormal, eg modeling returns for bonds and stocks, so lambda measures the riskiness of the portfolio. What are good series for approximating the quantile function near a particular portfolio value?

Comment: Thanks Matt F, I suppose $Y$ and $Z$ follow normal distribution and can confirm that this formula is correct. In fact, $F^{-1}_{Y+\lambda Z}(\alpha) = q_{\alpha}(\sigma_X^2 +\lambda^2\sigma_Y^2)^\frac{1}{2}$. But how to prove this formula in general case, when we don't have explicite formula of quantile function? I have no idea.

Comment: $F^{-1}_{X+\lambda Z}(\alpha)$, for fixed $\alpha$ is some function of $\lambda$: call it $g(\lambda)$ for short.  Then, if this is sufficiently differentiable, Taylor says $g(\lambda) = \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{d^n g}{d\lambda^n}(0) \frac{\lambda^n}{n!} + O(\lambda^{N+1})$.

Comment: Moreover, you can find the coefficients of the series of $g(\lambda)$ from the series for $F_{X+\lambda Z}(\alpha)$ by reversion of series.

Comment: Ah I see. The problem with this view become easy and evident, I don't know why I made it complicated. Thank you very much for your answer Robert!

Comment: You can have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem for that. Nevertheless, your problem seems more subtle if you do not assume a nice expansion in $ \lambda $. I would also be interested in an expression of the coefficients $ \frac{d^n g}{d\lambda^n}(0) $ in terms of, say, moments. This looks like an interesting way of estimating a quantile.